# Observer Pattern and Dependency Inversion

Tags: design-patterns

I have a controller class that implements `Observer` and another use-case class (called `UseCase`) (which is on a lower clean architecture layer) that extends `Observable`.

If my controller stores an instance of `UseCase` and calls `useCase.addObserver(this)`, is this breaking clean architecture, or is this an example of dependency inversion?

Comment: Why controller should listen events from domain logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP) is a design-time principle. Briefly stated:

> Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions

If the Controller in question depends on `Observable` and we assume that `Observable` is an interface or base class defined on the same level of abstraction (or higher) as the Controller, then the Controller depends on an abstraction.

If I understand the OP correctly, the `UseCase` class depends on the abstraction (`Observable`) because it extends it.

This all fits the DIP.

The fact that at run time an `Observable` instance like `UseCase` gets composed with the Controller doesn't change things. Due to polymorphism, the Controller doesn't depend on `UseCase`.

The assumption, however, is that some third party is responsible for composing the Controller with the `UseCase` instance. If the Controller news up the `UseCase` instance itself, then the DIP is violated because the Controller would depend on an implementation detail (the `UseCase` class).

Additionally, if the Controller stores an instance of `UseCase` instead of `Observer`, then, again, the DIP is violated.